# Accessing files outside directory root with slim and php

Tags: php, .htaccess, model-view-controller, twig, slim

Currently my file structure is as follows:

```
├── README.md
├── app
├── classes
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── database
├── public
├── templates
├── users
└── vendor
```

Inside of the `users` folder I have folders that relate to the username of the logged in user, each with their own files and folders defined by the user.

The issue I'm encountering is that I am unable to download files inside the `users` directory. Currently, I have my code working by moving the `users` directory inside of the `public` directory but there are pretty obvious security flaws to this. How would I make it so my users directory is one level up from the root as shown here but still able to be accessed by the `public` directory?

I've already tried using  `RewriteRule users/ ../users/` but it does not seem to work. I'm able to access the `users` directory through PHP, just not my front-controller in the `public` folder.

This is my first "real" project using Slim so I'm very new to this whole front-controller/mvc type thing. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Ok.  So a rewrite rule isn't going to resolve this as a rewrite rule on the web server isn't going to know if the user is authenticated.  You need to write routing logic inside your application for serving user files based on the user's permissions.  It's too broad to cover in one question/answer.

Comment: @Devon What if I made it so when a user clicks a file it sends a get request that will then call a route to grab the file. Would this be a viable way to go about doing this sort of thing? This route, of course, would validate that the folder is theirs.

Comment: Yes, that would be what you need to do.  In your routing logic or controller you'd need to verify the user has access to said file, then most likely use PHP to serve the file since it isn't accessible in the web path.

Comment: Now this raises another question, inside of PHP I'm unsure if you're able to "force" a download. For example, if a user visits a certain URL will PHP be able to serve them that file?

Comment: Great! Thank you for your help. After I get the basic site working I'll look into adding some Ajax calls to prevent multiple requests.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routing logic or controller you'd need to verify the user has access to said file, then most likely use PHP to serve the file since it isn't accessible in the web path.

In PHP, you can set the proper HTTP headers and use readfile() to serve files to the end user.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php